# Get user's current location using GPS

Tags: android, geolocation, gps

I'm new in android.
I'm currently working on an android project in witch I need to get user's current location using GPS.
But my code is not working properly.

**java Code**

```
package com.example.checkinapp;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity 
    {

        TextView textlat;
        TextView textlong;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            textlat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textlat);
            textlong = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textlong);

            LocationManager lm =   (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            LocationListener ll = new mylocationlistener();
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
        }
        class mylocationlistener implements LocationListener{

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                if(location!=null)
                {
                    double lat = location.getLatitude();
                    double lng = location.getLongitude();

                    textlat.setText(Double.toString(lat));
                    textlong.setText(Double.toString(lng));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                    Bundle extras) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        }
    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textlat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text=""
    android:ems="10">
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textlong"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:text=""
    android:ems="10">
</TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidMainfest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.checkinapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.checkinapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I'm trying to display the latitude and longitude of user to a textview.
But I'm not getting the result.
Thanks.

Comment: what is the problem? is you onLocationChanged() method is getting called? is the device GPS on? can you may be try to move near window or out of office to see if you can catch the GPS satellite..

Comment: Consider using the Google Play Services Location APIs, they're better tuned to save battery.

Answer (score 1):

```
LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) this .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
Location loc =   manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"My current location is: " + "Latitud =" +
  loc.getLatitude() + "Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: This is the simplest answer that just works. We can add error checks etc to improve but this answer should get more upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,
                        true);
                Location location = locationManager
                        .getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                if (location != null) {
                    onLocationChanged(location);
                }
                // updates location 30seconds once
                locationManager
                        .requestLocationUpdates(provider, 30000, 0, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use commonsware library instead..it is much stable than other codes ...you just have to download the library from here

https://github.com/commonsguy/downloads/blob/master/CWAC-LocationPoller.jar

and here is the code

```
public class LocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

  Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Received intent for " +   intent.getComponent().flattenToShortString());

        try {      
            Bundle b=intent.getExtras();

            LocationPollerResult locationResult = new LocationPollerResult(b);

            Location loc=locationResult.getLocation();
            String msg;

            if (loc==null) {
                loc=locationResult.getLastKnownLocation();

                if (loc==null) {
                    msg=locationResult.getError();
                }
                else {
                    msg="TIMEOUT, lastKnown="+loc.toString();
                }
            }
            else {
                msg=loc.toString();
            }

            if (msg==null) {
                msg="Invalid broadcast received!";      
            }

            Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "received location: " + msg);   

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the two methods how you can get user's location

- If you use NETWORK_PROVIDER, it works both indoor and outdoor but the acuuracy is quite less.
- If you use GPS_PROVIDER, it works outdoor only and the accuracy is good.

  String locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;

  String locationProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;

Along with the required permissions in the Manifest