# Get users current location android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-activity

I need your help. So i want to have the current location of the user. I want to have it as a String.

It would be great if somebody could help me ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of: [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290246/get-users-current-location-using-gps)

Answer (score 1):

Please check [Google Play services](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/location/retrieve-current.html) where is option to retrieve last known location or getting location udaptes via listener [Location updates](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/location/receive-location-updates.html)